# Adding a background image to a QQuickItem

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have created a `QPixmap` and drawn smaller `QPixmap`s on it  with `QPainter`. I want to use the image as the background of a `QQuickItem`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your custom item derived from `QQuickItem` you can redefine `QQuickItem::updatePaintNode()` in maybe this way:

```
QSGNode *MyItem::updatePaintNode(QSGNode *oldNode, QQuickItem::UpdatePaintNodeData *)
{
    QSGSimpleTextureNode *node = static_cast<QSGSimpleTextureNode *>(oldNode);
    if (!node) {
        node = new QSGSimpleTextureNode();
        QSGTexture *texture = window()->createTextureFromImage(m_pixmap.toImage());
        node->setTexture(texture);
    }
    node->setRect(boundingRect());
    return node;
}
```

*Pay attention: your item is owner of `QSGTexture *texture`, don't forget to delete it while object destruction.*

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.

Comment: what is `window()`? I derived from `QSGNode` and I create and use a new object of type `QQuickWindow`. Is this right?

Comment: Thank you @folibis. can you extend your code to explain how to delete texture?

Comment: @folibis Can you tell me how i can add a Image which have some transparent part?

Comment: `QSGTexture *texture = window()->createTextureFromImage(m_pixmap.toImage());` returns a null pointer. any idea why? I'm on Qt 5.10

Comment: What about aspect ratio?

Comment: Deleting `texture` inside the destructor of `MyItem` seems to result in an application crash (on iOS at least). A better approach may be to pass ownership of `texture` to `node`: [`node->setOwnsTexture(true);`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsgsimpletexturenode.html#setOwnsTexture)